# VBA - For loop throws Error 1004 after 5 passes

Tags: excel, vba7

I'm trying to write a VBA procedure to replace all #REF text in formulas with text from the first column of the worksheet which are also names of other sheets.

Each line has formulas from C to BC and the text from the first column varies by line.

The procedure works great for the first 4 rows and no matter what I do to the loop parameter, it will throw 1004 error (application-defined or object-defined error) on the 5th line.

PS.: First row of data is row 4, so the exception occurs when the loop reaches row 9.

I'd be glad to give more details if needed.

```
Sub Formulas()

    Dim m As Integer, pts As Worksheet, formstr As String
    Set pts = Sheets("Pontos")
    m = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(pts.Range("A5:A30"), "*") + 5
    For i = 5 To m
         For Each c In pts.Range("C" & i & ":BC" & i).Cells
            formstr = c.Formula
            formstr = Replace(formstr, "#REF", "'" & Cells(i, 1) & "'", , , vbTextCompare)
            c.Formula = formstr
         Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

I've tried different forms of loops and mess with i and whenever it's > 9 there will be an error.

Comment: `debug.print formstr` both before and after the replace to see if it makes sense.

Comment: Hi, Scott. Thanks for your reply. The formstr variable makes sense for the lines the loop runs correctly. I've tried debugging "i" and "m" as well but their values seem to be working ok.

Comment: When it errors, what are the outputs of `debug.print formstr` both before and after the replace?  Basically if it works but stops at some point the problem is almost always the data and not the code.

Comment: There are different formulas on different columns but here's an example of the successful replacement:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(Resultados!$AB$34:$AB$37=#REF!$R$34:$R$37))*12
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Resultados!$AB$34:$AB$37='Planilha11'!$R$34:$R$37))*12

Here's a fragment of the first formula loaded to formstr before it stops

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Resultados!$J$7),(ISNUMBER(Resultados!$K$7))),IF(AND(#REF!$J$7=Resultados!$J$7,#REF!$K$7=Resultados!$K$7)

=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Resultados!$J$7),(ISNUMBER(Resultados!$K$7))),IF(AND('Planilha11'!$J$7=Resultados!$J$7,'Planilha11'!$K$7=Resultados!$K$7)

Comment: I want to see what the formula you are trying to place when it fails, not when it succeeds.

Comment: The formulas are the same on every line of a column except for the worksheets they reference to

Comment: So after further investigation I found what seems to be the problem.

Somewhere in the process, the cell references where erased from the formula after the #REF error happened

I'll see what can I do to recover from previous versions

For now, thanks a lot for your suggestions, Scott. I'll come back after I figure it out to end the thread and vote your answer.

Comment: Hi Scott. So just to close this thread, it was indeed a problem with the reference to the cells. I didn't know that the cell addresses for #REF issues are erased when the workbook is closed and that's what was causing the issue. I deeply appreciate your inputs and apologize for wasting your time and goodwill. Let me know how can I give feedback for your help. Cheers